# Read only permission/scope for DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

As mentioned on the link https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant, there are three access scopes DocuSign allows to fetch user's data : signature, extended and impersonation.
I am looking for a scope which allows me only read access. I need to build a dashboard of various activities/updates (getting the status of all envelopes, etc) of all the users of DocuSign at my company.

As per my understanding, I need 'signature' permissions/scope at-least as described under heading "Admin consent for internal applications" on https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent.

This means I will have access to create and delete the envelopes as well. Couldn't understand the 'extended' scope as well (as per my reading, it is helping to extend the access tokens validity and usage of refresh token any number of times).

Is their any other permission type (read scope only) that I can use based on my criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Re read only scope. Not at this time. And since you want stats for all users' envelopes, you'll need Account Wide Rights. Full Admin is not necessary.

Perhaps an alternative might be to use the connect webhook system, and then track statistics as your app receives each notification message about changes to the users' envelopes.